# Is there a related function to display more than one page at the created PDF file in NetSuite

Tags: javascript

I need to get a list of all the pick tickets available 
and then 
display all the pick tickets related in one pdf file

All that I can get is just one page for one id

```
   var transactionFile = render.pickingTicket({
       entityId: 501,
       printMode: render.PrintMode.xml,
       location :1423,
       inCustLocale: false    });

     transactionFile.folder = 1423;
        var id = transactionFile.save();
            }
return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if you are going to use the render.pickingTicket method of the render module, because that module can only process one record.

The not so easiest way to do it is to create a saved search with all the data or transactions you need. Then create an advanced PDF template and script that will use render.xmlToPdf to convert your PDF template into a single PDF.